# Did Negan force Enid to poison Maggie?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In *The Walking Dead* TV show, did Negan force Enid to poison Maggie? Think about it: Negan would've had to have known they would leave, when, why and where they were going.

My theory is that Enid isn't a bad person, but based on the comics, Carl falls in love with a girl who is a traitor of sorts, in the comics it's a different group and different circumstances, but it still fits.

The saviours would have HAD TO HAVE known WAY ahead of time that Maggie would need help. And who is the last person she's with before she falls down in agonizing pain? Enid. Not only was she seen giving Maggie the advice, "prop your feet up, have some pickles", she came back to make sure Maggie fell sick.. just odd. Not sure. But I kinda feel that'd be a good one for them to throw at us.

Comment: I don't watch TWD, but from your question it sounds as though the answer may be unknown until future episodes of the show come out. You might like to have a look at our [policy on questions based on future works](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based).

Comment: By 'Edith', I assume you actually meant '[Enid](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Enid_(TV_Series))' (who was with Maggie when she got sick)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the episodes that aired so far, there is no evidence that Enid poisoned Maggie, and no evidence that Enid was working for Negan.

Enid got pickles for Maggie probably because she thought that the pregnant Maggie wanted them. [Pickles are commonly thought to be craved by pregnant women.](https://www.google.com/search?q=pregnancy%20pickles)

Rick and company getting captured by the Saviors is just a result of a well-prepared plan on the Saviors' part. The Saviors at that point have scouted out Alexandria and were well aware of its location. From S06E15, "East":

> Jiro (a Savior): Miles, what's that place called? The gated one 12.75 clicks down?
>
> Miles: Alexandria.
>
> Jiro: Yeah, Alexandria. You know, they got some cars out front, spikes
>   through them, just like the one you're driving.
>   ...
>   Jiro: You know, we
>   were just on our way to your place. We can give you a ride back.

The Saviors prepared well in advance to prepare a trap for Rick and company. Based on what we've seen of the Saviors, they have the equipment and manpower to scout around Alexandria and block the roads out of it. From S06E16, "Last Day on Earth":

> Negan: Today was career day. We invested a lot so you would know who I
>   am and what I can do.